# lock-keys-applet alternative for Kubuntu

Tags: dell, kubuntu, capslock

Is there any lock-keys-applet alternative to kubuntu. I just want some indication whenever I use caps lock or num lock key. I am using dell inspiron n5010 laptop and it does not have inbuilt indicator. Thanks

Comment: It worked for me (Ubuntu Budgie 17.10) http://tipsonubuntu.com/2014/05/23/caps-lock-indicator-ubuntu-1404/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have solved it, the solution is to install `plasma-widget-kbstate`

```
sudo apt-get install plasma-widget-kbstate
```